# Query cross referencing dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

I'm stuck with some list/dictionary work. Here's a part of the first list of dictionaries I have

```
{'createdTime': '2017-11-18T11:11:42.223Z',
 'fields': {'Pair ID': 307,
            'Source': ['recmSPeRUDk7JxTEs'],
            'Target': ['recEijqlS0kjmIjpL']},
 'id': 'rec02AuJ8QzEZR56b'}
```

In `Source` and `Target` it references entries from another dictionary that looks like this (stripped by everything not relevant here)

```
{'createdTime': '2017-11-05T17:14:59.000Z',
 'fields': {'Name': 'John',
            'E-Mail': 'john@example.com ',
 'id': 'rec0KMaG8L7qldPuI'}
```

The link is through the id field. So Source and Target from the above dictionary reference an entry in the second. I know need to send emails to every Source from the above dictionary while iterating through the list.

Both are lists of dictionaries. My question is do I need to iterate through the second list too or is there a way to reference the record matching the Source from above in a smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way your data is formatted the answer is yes you have to iterate because dictionaries are meant to be used when you know the key and that you want to have the corresponding value. Here you want to retrieve the key knowing the value which is the reverse situation.

Now if this is what you want I would recommend modifying the structure of your data so that the `id` is not a field but directly the key of your dict. for example:

```
events_recorded = {
    'rec02AuJ8QzEZR56b' :
        {'createdTime': '2017-11-18T11:11:42.223Z',
         'fields': {
                    'Pair ID': 307,
                    'Source': ['recmSPeRUDk7JxTEs'],
                    'Target': ['recEijqlS0kjmIjpL']},
        },
    'recRkckX9nfl5VhWk' :
         {'createdTime': '2017-11-18T12:05:42.223Z',
         'fields': {
                    'Pair ID': 45,
                    'Source': ['reclfUAfAmCRlmuKw'],
                    'Target': ['recMIG7mm7eNZ79IC']},
        },
    'receeyCtLXIA2r1dw' :
         {'createdTime': '2017-11-18T12:05:42.223Z',
         'fields': {
                    'Pair ID': 45,
                    'Source': ['recnQPVxk5Lvv73xz'],
                    'Target': ['recMV3zbkgevDEgr0y']},
        },

}


addressbook = {
    'rec0KMaG8L7qldPuI' :
        {'createdTime': '2017-11-05T17:14:59.000Z',
         'fields': {'Name': 'John',
                    'E-Mail': 'john@example.com '}
         },
    'reclfUAfAmCRlmuKw' :
         {'createdTime': '2017-10-05T03:43:02.000Z',
         'fields': {'Name': 'Ehtel',
                    'E-Mail': 'ethel@example.com '}
         },
    'recMV3zbkgevDEgr0y' :
         {'createdTime': '2017-10-05T03:43:02.000Z',
         'fields': {'Name': 'Gertrude',
                    'E-Mail': 'gertrude@example.com '}
         },

    }
```

You could then do things like:

```
reference_wanted = events_recorded['rec02AuJ8QzEZR56b']['fields']['Source'][0]
email_wanted = addressbook[reference_wanted]['fields']['E-Mail']
```

But it depends on how your data is structured